# copy node_module/@type/koa to my custom typeRoots，why not work？

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, koa, antd

i wan use antd ui, and hope use script tag label import `.min.js`， like this

```
<script src="//cdn.staticfile.org/react/15.4.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.staticfile.org/react/15.4.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.staticfile.org/react/15.4.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/antd/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
```

and my webpack.config.js is

```
externals: {  
    "react": "React",  
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",  
    "antd": "antd"  
},
```

tsconfig.json is

```
{  
"compilerOptions": {  
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "target": "es5",  
    "allowJs": true,  
    "noImplicitAny": false,  
    "sourceMap": false,  
    "jsx": "react",  
    "watch": true,  
    "typeRoots": ["./h"],  
    "traceResolution": true,  
    "lib": [  
        "es6",  
        "dom"  
    ]  
},  
"exclude": [  
    "node_modules",  
    "src/server/assets",  
    "src/client",  
    "webpack.config.js"  
]  
 }
```

```

firstly i use namespace, i think antd function in antd objetc **ptotype**, like global module, like jquery.

/h/antd/index.d.ts

```
import * as React from "react";

declare namespace antd{
    export let DatePicker: typeof React.Component;
}

declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        "DatePicker": any;
    }
}
```

```

```
import * as antd from "antd";
let DatePicker: typeof React.Component = antd.DatePicker;

ReactDOM.render(
    <DatePicker />,
    document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

they give me an error: can't find antd module.

and i am try define a modlue

```
import * as React from "react";


declare module "antd2"{
  export let DatePicker: typeof React.Component;
}

declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
    "DatePicker": any;
    }
}
```

and i once again get the error： no find module

if i take antd2 floder copy to node_modules/@types ，i find is‘s work，why？

so i try copy koa types to h floder，i find koa is not work，why？

and i give my `h/all.d.ts` `declare module "*"` ， I still get this mistake。 why？

all the error sample code in `https://github.com/MiYogurt/ts-koa-react/tree/error`

3Q for you help！

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use the CommonJS version of antd in in development, thus you can use antd's type declaration for free, and you can config antd as a external dependency when you are building production bundle.